# Trying to change my data during a .map call

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

During a .map from an array of data, I have another array of data, which I need to do a .map inside it too.
It's looking a bit like this

First Data load

```
async function handleSubmit(event: FormEvent){
    event.preventDefault();
    await api.get(`people/?search=${input}`).then(response =>{
        setCharacters(response.data.results)
    })
}
```

Second Data Load

```
   async function getFilmName(film: string) {
        const movie = film.split("/");
        await api.get(`films/${movie[5]}`).then(response =>{
           return(response.data.title)
        })
  }
```

and then, the .map's

```
 {characters.map(characters =>{
            return (
                <div>
                    <Link to={`character/${characters.url.split("/")[5]}`}>{characters.name}</Link>
                    {characters.films.map((films) =>{
                        return(
                            <h5>{getFilmName(films)}</h5>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            )
        })}
```

and, in the end I receive a

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Comment: {characters.map(****characters**** =>{
Here can you use a different name here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getFilmName` is Promise object. So It can't get file name in JSX context.
So you need to use it in `useEffect` or other event handler and you need to save data in `state`. And you can render with right data.

And in that case, you can make some new component like,

```
function FileName ({file}){
  const [fileName,setFileName] = useState("")
  const getFileName = useCallback(async ()=> {...},[file])
  useEffect(()=>{
      getFileName()
  },[getFileName])
  return (<h5>{fileName}</h5>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you ware using same variable name here

```
 {characters.map(character =>{
            return (
                <div>
                    <Link to={`character/${character.url.split("/")[5]}`}>{character.name}</Link>
                    {character.films.map((films) =>{
                        return(
                            <h5>{getFilmName(films)}</h5>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            )
        })}
```